# Como mudar a estrutura de um método estático em tempo de execução?

Tags: java, rest, http, httpclient, java-11

Estou construindo uma aplicação em Java que consome um Web Service REST. Busquei utilizar o novo HttpClient do Java 11. Porém, uma mesma requisição nessa aplicação de destino às vezes recebe um post, às vezes recebe um GET mas com o mesmo cabeção mudando apenas o método.

Nos exemplos que encontrei na Internet eu invoco o método do HttpRequest e vou construindo ele com .Metodo1().Metodo2() e assim por diante. Entáo no meu caso de uso como às vezes eu tenho GET às vezes POST mas o cabeçalho e URL são os mesmos, preciso fazer o seguinte:

```
private HttpResponse<String> getResponse() throws IOException, InterruptedException {

    HttpRequest request;

    if(post) {
        request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(url))
                .POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(payload))
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();

    } else {
        request = HttpRequest.newBuilder()
                .uri(URI.create(url))
                .GET()
                .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                .build();
    }

    return httpClient.send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
}
```

Estou fazendo um IF e tendo que repetir a mesma estrutura inteira, teria como eu intervir no meio disso com tipo um ternário para ter somente um método?

Observação importante: mesmo se for possível usar o HttpClient / HttpRequest de outra forma gostaria que fosse preservado dessa forma até para que eu possa entender melhor, pois não é o primeiro exemplo do genero que vejo, já vi o mesmo cenário no Twilio ML usando esse "builder" para construir o XML, e lá um mesmo parâmetro pode se repetir, exemplo:

```
Message message = new Message.Builder().body(body).body(body1).media(media).build();
```

E se eu quisesse repetir N vezes no caso do Twilio? Como faria?

Tem um nome para essa estrutura de encadeamento de métodos?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se entendi bem o que quer, não dá. Você quer tipo um ternário que chama métodos distintos conforme uma condição, correto? O Java não suporta isso, eu pelo menos nunca vi.

Esse encadeamento de métodos vem de um padrão de projeto chamado *Builder*. Ele vai montando parcialmente o objeto até finalizar com a chamada `build()`, que retorna o objeto montado.

Um conceito parecido é o de *fluent interface*, você pode procurar exemplos por aí usando esse termo.

Se quisesse repetir o header três vezes, faria assim:

```
HttpRequest.newBuilder()
            .uri(URI.create(url))              
.POST(HttpRequest.BodyPublishers.ofString(payload))
            .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
            .header("outra chave", "outro valor")
            .header("mais uma chave", "mais um valor")
            .build();
```

---

### Editado:

Uma característica do padrão de projeto *Builder* é que enquanto o objeto está incompleto, seus métodos de preparação como por exemplo o `header()` retornam o respectivo "builder", que podemos chamar de objeto parcialmente pronto. Esse objeto não pertence à classe `HttpRequest` mas sim a uma classe auxiliar (ou melhor, interface), a `HttpRequest.Builder`. Depois, quando estiver pronto, chama-se o método `build()` desse "builder" e o objeto pronto é entregue a você.

Não está muito claro por que você só sabe o número de headers durante a execução, mas como você está nessa situação, pode guardar o "builder" parcialmente pronto e chamá-lo conforme vai descobrindo que há novos headers para adicionar. O "builder" é o objeto que é retornado pelo método `header()` e outros métodos de `HttpRequest`.

Não coloco exemplo em código porque não compreendi totalmente o cenário que você tem aí.

Comment: Piovezan obrigado pela rápida resposta. Está bem alinhado com o que estou esperando, agora com o nome do pattern eu já estou pesquisando sobre o assunto para me especializar mais. Mas ainda resta uma dúvida, usando esse mesmo exemplo que você deu, se eu conheço a quantidade de header somente durante a execução, como faria para adicionar vários .header (de acordo com a demanda). Partindo da premissa que não existe o método .headers (com s no final) nesse exemplo. Como encapsular isso em uma classe minha já que náo existe um ternário pra isso?

Comment: Editei a resposta.

Comment: Obrigado! Me orientou muito com relação ao padrão Builder :D